# Create get request in a webdriver with selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, python-requests

Is it possible to send a get request to a webdriver using selenium?

I want to scrape a website with an infinite page and want to scrape a substantial amount of the objects on the website. For this I use Selenium to open the website in a webdriver and scroll down the page until enough objects on the page are visible.

However, I'd like to scrape the information on the page with BeautifulSoup since this is the most effective way in this case. If the get request is send in the normal way (see the code) the response only holds the first objects and not the objects from the scrolled-down page (which makes sence).

But is there any way to send a get request to an open webdriver?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

```
# Opening the website in the webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver.get(url)
```

```
# Loop for scrolling
scroll_start = 0
for i in range(100):
    scroll_end = scroll_start + 1080
    driver.execute_script(f'window.scrollTo({scroll_start}, {scroll_end})') 
    time.sleep(2)
    scroll_start = scroll_end
```

```
# The get request
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'lxml')
```

Answer (score 0):

You should probably find out what is the endpoint that the website is using to get the data for the infinite scrolling.

Go to the website, open the Dev Tools, open the Network tab and find the HTTP request that is asking for the content you're seeking, then MAYBE you can use it too. Just know that there are a lot of variables like, are they using some sort of authorization for their APIs? Are the APIs returning JSON, XML, HTML, ...? Also, I am not sure if this is fair-use.